# Google Sheets Cryptofinance Add-on - is the company still operating?

Tags: cryptofinance

I sent in some support emails since May 14 and have not heard back. Anyone aware if the developer is still operating this add-on for Google Sheets?

> > > Update, they replied today (May 23) and resolved my inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so, I've had a reply to my emails and telegram messages just few days ago. Maybe they are too busy with this (mini) bull market?